# Is nonlinearity a denser encoding of information?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, non-linear-systems, boltzmann-equation

At the microscopic level, an $n$-particle system in 3D can be described by the Liouville equation, which governs the evolution of the distribution function in a $6n$-dimensional phase space.

Going through the BBGKY hierarchy leads to the Boltzmann equation, which is now in a 6-dimensional phase space, but may be nonlinear if there is an external time-evolving force (like in a plasma).

By taking moments of the Boltzmann equation we eventually arrive at the fluid equations (or the two-fluid equations in plasmas), which are nonlinear and in 3 dimensions.

So, we have a system with far fewer degrees of freedom, but now it's nonlinear. Is it fair to say that nonlinearity is a denser encoding of information, or is there no correlation between nonlinearity and information?

Answer (score 0):

Linearity is a property of an equation, and in physics we may have both kinds of equation describing exactly the same model.

The same system (e.g., an anharmonic 1D oscillator) can be described using either a non-linear ordinary differential equation (equation of motion), or a linear partial differential equation (the Liouville equation).

Both kinds of equations can describe the motion of a single system equally well, the first using a coordinate $r(t)$, the other using a singular probability distribution function $\rho (x,t) = \delta(x-r(t))$.

Here we can go from linear to non-linear description without changing the number of degrees of freedom, and without losing any information. The non-linear equation is simpler to work with, but I would not call it "denser information".

In your example, you seem to call the 3D description "denser information" because it has less degrees of freedom. But in the reduction process there, it seems, some information is lost from the descriptive probability function, e.g. correlations between different degrees of freedom. So its a "lossy compression".